# I am trying to make an English to Spanish conjugator in Python. Need assistance

Tags: python

```
verb_1 = raw_input("Enter a word")
verb_2 = verb_1.lower()
verb_2_ending = verb_2[len(verb_2)-1:len(verb_2)]:
print verb_2_ending
```

This is my code so far, and it will not work!! Could someone help explain why...
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as well.
I don't quite understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: "it will not work" - how does it not work? Are you getting any errors? What's the expected output for a given input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
verb_2_ending = verb_2[-1:]
```

I think is what you want ... but maybe you have more questions?

It was not working because you have an extra `:` at the end of the verb_2_ending line